# Java equivalent of Spring XML configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to figure out what the Java equivalent to this piece of Spring XML:

```
<bean id="foo" class="x.y.Foo">
    <property name="name" value="Rick"/>
</bean>
```

Where value is an `EncryptablePropertiesFactoryBean`. I have it working with the XML configuration but I can't seem to find a Java alternative anywhere.

Comment: Please include a proper snippet you want to translate.  You probably need a ref instead of value etc. without a proper sample it is impossible to tell what to translate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this one. The Qualifier is the key part here.

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public x.y.Foo foo(@Qualifier("encryptedProperties") Properties properties){
        x.y.Foo foo = new x.y.Foo();
        foo.setPropertiesWithCustomSetter(properties);
        return foo;
    }

    @Bean
    public EncryptablePropertiesFactoryBean encryptedProperties() {
        // Build EncryptablePropertiesFactoryBean with whatever encrypted properties you need
        return new EncryptablePropertiesFactoryBean ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to implement beans, I would suggest read this documentation for more comprenhention about how Spring uses beans:

[Spring IoC vs DI](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-core/spring-ioc-vs-di/)

For the answer, a programatic way to do this could be:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public x.y.Foo foo(){
    // make something here
     EncryptablePropertiesFactoryBean Rick = new EncryptablePropertiesFactoryBean() // or any other instance of this
     return new x.y.Foo(Rick); //Where x.y.Foo has a property in its constructor of this type
  }

}
```